# JsonLayout maximum message length?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Is there a way to limit the characters of the message value in JsonLayout of log4j2? Current configuration is something like this

```
<Console name="CONSOLE_APPENDER" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <BurstFilter level="INFO" rate="2" maxBurst="10"/>
        <JsonLayout compact="false" eventEol="false" stacktraceAsString="true">
            <KeyValuePair key="timestamp" value="$${date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}" />
            <KeyValuePair key="BuildNumber" value="$${ctx:BuildNumber:-}"/>
        </JsonLayout>
    </Console>
```

Comment: I think you could but with PatternLayout instead.

Comment: There seems to be an open ticket for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2525